# Converting a string (p01..p02..p03) to a string/int?

Tags: c#

Im new to programming.. I need to convert a string of patients from the database as p01 p02 p03... to create a newid when I enter a new patient into the database. I currently have this code but I have done it wrong.. any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
public void patientInsert()         
{
        hospitalSQLEntities db = new hospitalSQLEntities();
        int newid = 0;
    if (db.patients.Count() ==0)
          newid = 1; 
else
newid = db.patients.Max(u => u.PatientID) + 1;
...
```

Comment: what type are they in the database?

Comment: generally, you should let your database assign the next id/key.

Comment: it is a string in the database from p01 p02 p03.. etc. Does this help?

Comment: then it should be a string already.

Comment: I need to create a new id for each consecutive patients. Is the above code right then? I was told it was wrong. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should let the DB assign the primary key. Most commonly the primary key is an integer and marked as [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and automatically assigned by the database when you insert a row into the table.

For SQL server you can designate the primary key to be Identity in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]